# Next.js GetStream - Trying to get the data in realtime using notification feed and useQuery

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getstream-io

I have a problem getting the data in realtime from getstream using getstream SDK and useQuery from react-query lib. Basically I want to fetch the data whenever there is a new notification. I just do not receive the data on client side no matter I do.

Here is the code:

```
const userTimelineFeedEvents = client.feed('notification', userId, token)

const { data: notificationData, refetch } = useNotifications()


useEffect(() => {
      let subscription: Subscription

      const subscriptionFunction = async () => {
        if (userTimelineFeedEvents) {
          userTimelineFeedEvents
            .subscribe(async (data) => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(data)) // this never gets called
            })
            .then((sub) => {
              subscription = sub
            })
        }
      }

      subscriptionFunction()

      return () => {
        if (subscription) {
          subscription.cancel()
        }
      }
    }, [userTimelineFeedEvents, refetch])
```

useNotification is a hook which needs to display the data, but I create new notification on server. I do not have the code for that, but I can assure you that new data gets created and it is inside the GetStream dashboard

I only tried to get the data inside the useEffect, because I need to subscribe whenever there is new data.

P.S: I get the data when I refresh the page but that is not the point, it is not realtime